Not able to create a release workitem using CreateWorkItem@2 task
I am trying to create a release work item using azure pipeline task "CreateWorkItem@2" but the pipeline is failing due to TF401320: Rule Error for field Description error.
Task Code"
- task: CreateWorkItem@2
  inputs:
    teamProject: $(project)
    workItemType: 'Release'
    title: $(title)
    assignedTo: '$(Build.RequestedFor)'
    areaPath: $(areaPath)
    iterationPath: ${{ parameters.IterationPath }}
    fieldMappings: '[Description=This has been bulk created by CWI task, 
                     Transition Management Approved=No, Not required.]'
    authType: 'internal'

Wants create a release work item using
CreateWorkItem@2



TF401320: Rule Error for field Description error.

Based on your YAML definition, the cause of the issue is that the Description field value not input the correct value when creating work item.
To solve this issue, you need to change the fieldMappings field of the CreateWorkItem@2 with the following format:
fieldMappings: |
 field1=value1
 field2=value2

Task example:
- task: CreateWorkItem@2
  inputs:
    teamProject: $(project)
    workItemType: 'Release'
    title: $(title)
    assignedTo: '$(Build.RequestedFor)'
    areaPath: $(areaPath)
    iterationPath: ${{ parameters.IterationPath }}
    fieldMappings: |
     Description=This has been bulk created by CWI task
     Transition Management Approved=No, Not required.
    authType: 'internal'

In this case, the Description and  Transition Management Approved field will be input the correct value when creating work items.

Thanks, i am able to create the work item using pipeline
